# Using AppleScript to change text color in Keynote

Tags: applescript, keynote

I am tired of clicking through the color wheel to get custom colors and I would like to use AppleScript to automate with BTT a simple button to change the selected text color to a set of company standards.  I have been able to get as far as opening up the Color Picker in Keynote with AppleScript, but I can't figure out how to click the pencil.  Here is what Accessibility Inspector shows:
[image: Color picker Blueberry pencil]

This is my code so far, but the selection to click Blueberry pencil keeps complaining that

> System Events got an error: Can’t get window "Text Color" of application process "Keynote".

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Keynote"
        tell radio group of toolbar of window 1
            -- This prevents it from toggling the button when already selected
            if value of radio button "Format" = {{0}} then
                click radio button "Format"
            end if
        end tell
        tell scroll area 1 of window 1
            click color well 1
        end tell
    end tell
    tell application "System Events"
        tell window "Text Color" of application process "Keynote"
            tell splitter group 1
                tell radio group "Pencils"
                    click radio button "Blueberry"
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Keynote**, if I select some *text* and run the following *example* **AppleScript** *code*, the *color* of the *text* is set to **Blueberry**:

```
activate application "Keynote"
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "Keynote"
        tell window 1
            tell radio group of toolbar 1
                if value of radio button 1 = {{0}} then
                    click radio button 1
                end if
            end tell
            click color well of scroll area 1
            click button 5 of toolbar 1
            click radio button 33 of radio group 1 of splitter group 1
            click button 1
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

If you want to use the *pencil color name* instead of the *radio button number*, then change:

```
click radio button 33 of radio group 1 of splitter group 1
```

To:

```
click (every radio button of radio group 1 of splitter group 1 whose description is "Blueberry")
```

<sup>Hint: Mouse over and horizontal scroll to see full *code*.</sup>

You can then substitute any valid *pencil color* for a different *color* then `"Blueberry"`.

**Note:** The *example* **AppleScript** *code* was tested and worked, as is, on my **Mac** running **macOS High Sierra** and **Keynote** version 8.1 (5683).

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [delay](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) command may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: Can this same code work for Numbers?  The menu seems to have the same structure and it gets as far as selecting the Text radio button, but the click color well action doesn't open the color well so the next command fails.

Comment: @naven87, Assuming the target is _selected text_ in a _cell_ then here's the **UI Scripting** _code_ reworked for **Numbers**: https://paste.ee/p/XZxzW

Comment: Thank you again, how are you identify that it was scroll area 4 in the Paste link.  I used the accessibility inpector tool, but couldn't see anything that indicated there was more than one scroll area.  I even experimented with incrementing the scroll area index, but quit at 3 :(

Comment: @naven87,Using **Accessibility Inspector** and holding it over the **color well** I saw its description was "color well", and knowing its hierarchy was **AXApplication** > **AXWindow:ACStandardWindow** > **AXScrollArea** > **AXColorWell** I used the _query_, `tell application "System Events" to get every UI element of every scroll area of window 1 of application process "Numbers" whose description = "color well"` which returned `{{}, {}, {}, {color well 1 of scroll area 4 of window "Untitled" of application process "Numbers" of application "System Events"}}`, cont. ...

Comment: @naven87, ...cont. so I knew it was `color well 1 of scroll area 4` and used it. BTW There were other differences in the _code_ as well. Compare them side by side, line for line and you'll see.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on getting AppleScript to report all the scroll areas.  I saw the change to check if the "Text" button (radio button 3) is selected, but since that doesn't seem to have any negative consequence when clicked if already selected (unlike the Format button) I left it alone.  I did make a change in my code to explicitly click radio button "Text"  because I found at least in Keynote the number of radio buttons changed depending on what was on the slide.  Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 0):

Keynote has scripting support to change the colour (and size and font) of text, so you can make changes without relying upon UI scripting.

It uses an RGB model where you provide a 16-bit number for each colour. These values can be derived by multiplying the RGB value by 257. For example, Blueberry has values of {0, 0, 255}; multiply by 257 and you get the {0, 0, 65535} below. Conversely, if you divide each of the 'added text' colours of {25441, 10793, 42404} by 257, you end up with 99/42/165 (or #632AA5).

```
tell application "Keynote"
    tell slide 1 of document 1
        --Title
        set the color of object text of the default title item to {0, 0, 65535}
        set the font of object text of the default title item to "Impact"
        set size of the object text of default title item to 54

        --Body
        set the color of object text of the default body item to {8481, 32896, 16704}
        set the font of object text of the default body item to "Impact"
        set size of the object text of default body item to 36

        --Added text
        set color of the object text of text item 3 to {25441, 10793, 42404}
        set the font of object text of the text item 3 to "Impact"
        set size of the object text of text item 3 to 24
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: The issue is the text is already written and I'm trying to only colorize selected text within an existing text item.  I couldn't see a way to set the color property for the currently selected text without automating the UI or going through some cut and paste gymnastics.

Comment: Makes sense. Apple seems to have issues with using applescript to work with selected text.